# What is the difference between BS Zelda and the original Zelda1?

Tags: version-differences, the-legend-of-zelda

And what does the BS mean anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BS stands for [Broadcast Satellite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_Satellite_(Japanese)) (not "Broadcast Satellaview", which is a common mistake). The [Satellaview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellaview) was an interesting piece of kit - a satellite modem for the Super Famicom, released only in Japan.

[BS Zelda no Densetsu](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/BS_Zelda_no_Densetsu) (BS ゼルダの伝説) was a rewritten version of the original Legend of Zelda, downloadable from the satellite in four installments. Installments were broadcast at a specific time, because the game featured a live voice narration that at intervals offered gameplay clues over streaming audio! It also had a real-time clock that triggered specific events.

The game has the same basic mechanics as the original, but features entirely different dungeons. There are some minor changes to the layout of the Overworld and the Rupee limit, and Link is replaced by a choice of male or female Satellaview mascots ([a boy](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Mascot_%28male%29) with green hair and a backward baseball cap, [a girl](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Mascot_%28female%29) with red hair).

See also Wikipedia, which has a small amount of [additional information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda_%28video_game%29#Sequels).

Answer (score 1):

The BS Zelda games were a tiny bit different but in some cases very similar:

- Most sprites and costumes are the same or slightly changed. For example: The main character
- BS Zelda was only playable for a certain amount of time a week until it was shut down
- first Zelda game with real-time weather. For example: during 4:00 - 5:00 the game would rain for all players online
- different story, including some of the main characters and new ones
- the world map was similar but some things were moved or changed

Hope I could help. Here's a link for more info...

(I did **not** create this video)